# Group by using date and count matching word in log file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by, count

I have myFileMonitor.log file with below data. I want to save data in csv file as below based on group by date and match word like - *'Created', 'modified', 'moved', 'deleted'*. So here in the log file I want to filter data based on Date and I want to count how many time those words occurred in the log. Please assist.

```
myFileMonitor.log:
2020-09-25 16:31:58 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/New folder ' has been Created!!
2020-09-25 16:32:11 - Security Alert! Files/Folder moved ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/New folder ' to ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/Test1 '
2020-09-25 16:32:12 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/Test1 - Copy ' has been Created!!
2020-09-25 16:32:13 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/Test1 - Copy ' has been modified!
2020-09-25 16:32:30 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/Code.png ' has been Created!!
2020-09-25 16:32:30 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/Code.png ' has been modified!
2020-09-25 16:32:30 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/Code.png ' has been modified!
2020-09-25 16:32:30 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/Code.png ' has been modified!
2020-09-25 16:32:30 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/Code.png ' has been modified!
2020-09-25 16:32:30 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/PsedoCode.png ' has been Created!!
2020-09-25 16:32:30 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/PsedoCode.png ' has been modified!
2020-09-25 16:32:30 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/PsedoCode.png ' has been modified!
2020-09-25 16:32:30 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/PsedoCode.png ' has been modified!
2020-09-25 16:32:30 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/PsedoCode.png ' has been modified!
2020-09-25 16:33:56 - Security Alert! Files/Folder deleted: C:/Users/khond/Downloads/Test1!
2020-09-25 16:34:04 - Security Alert! Files/Folder moved ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/Test1 - Copy ' to ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/Test1 '
2020-09-25 16:34:05 - Security Alert! Files/Folder deleted: C:/Users/khond/Downloads/Code.png!
2020-09-25 16:34:11 - Security Alert! Files/Folder moved ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/PsedoCode.png ' to ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/Code.png '
2020-09-25 16:34:11 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/Code.png ' has been modified!
2020-09-30 19:02:45 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/New folder ' has been Created!!
2020-09-30 19:02:52 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/New folder - Copy ' has been Created!!
2020-09-30 19:02:53 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/New folder - Copy ' has been modified!
2020-09-30 19:02:53 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/New folder - Copy (2) ' has been Created!!
2020-09-30 19:02:54 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/New folder - Copy (2) ' has been modified!
2020-09-30 19:02:55 - Security Alert! Files/folder deleted: C:/Users/khond/Downloads/New folder - Copy (2)!
2020-09-30 19:03:07 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/New Rich Text Document.rtf ' has been Created!!
2020-09-30 19:03:07 - Security Alert! ' C:/Users/khond/Downloads/New Rich Text Document.rtf ' has been modified!
2020-09-30 19:03:13 - Security Alert! Files/folder deleted: C:/Users/khond/Downloads/New Rich Text Document.rtf!
2020-09-30 19:03:16 - Security Alert! Files/folder deleted: C:/Users/khond/Downloads/New folder - Copy!
```

```
I want the output as below:
2020-09-25,Created,4
2020-09-25,modified,9
2020-09-25,deleted,2
2020-09-25,moved,3
2020-09-30,Created,4
2020-09-30,modified,3
2020-09-30,deleted,3
```

I am new with python, try to write a function as below

```
def collect_data():
    try:
        file_name = 'myFileMonitor.log'
        with open(file_name) as f:
            contents = f.read()
            count_for_deleted = contents.count("deleted")
            count_for_created = contents.count("created")
            count_for_modified = contents.count("modified")
            count_for_moved = contents.count("moved")
        print(count_for_deleted)
        print(count_for_created)
        print(count_for_modified)
        print(count_for_moved)

        occurrences = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

        with open('myFileMonitor.log', 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                date = line.split(' ')[0]
                name = line.split(' - ')[1].split(': ')[0]
                occurrences[date][name] += 1

        for elem in occurrences:
            print(elem[0], ' :: ', elem[1])

            #print(occurrences)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Exception error: File not found!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very much on the right track using a defaultdict, but there's an easy way to check whether a key is in a line, and that's the `in` keyword.  If you know what your keywords are beforehand, then this is the code I would use:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def collect_data():
    try:
        occurrences = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
        keys = {'Created', 'modified', 'deleted', 'moved'}
        with open('myFileMonitor.log', 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                date = line.split(' ')[0]
                for key in keys:
                    if key in line:
                        occurrences[date][key] += 1

        for date in occurrences:
            for key in occurrences[date]:
                print(date+','+key+','+str(occurrences[date][key]))

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Exception error: File not found!")
```

Output:

```
2020-09-25,Created,4
2020-09-25,moved,3
2020-09-25,modified,10
2020-09-25,deleted,2
2020-09-30,Created,4
2020-09-30,modified,3
2020-09-30,deleted,3
```

You can also do things like defining an order you'd like to print the dates and keys or sorting before the loop if necessary.